# Change interpolation brackets - Angular2

Tags: laravel, angular, interpolation, laravel-blade, brackets

I want to use Laravel Blade and AngularJS.

Is some way to change interpolate sintax, change {{text}} for [{text}] or somthing like that?

I already change all components.ts files adding the line:
`interpolation: ["{[", "]}"],`
 but, where I write blade, app breaks...

Thanks a lot everybody ;)

Comment: Solved, I need change my BladeCompiler.php and create again the function SetContentTag (removed by laravel in lastest update).
Function Below.

Comment: public function setContentTags($openTag, $closeTag, $escaped = false)
 {
  $property = ($escaped === true) ? 'escapedTags' : 'contentTags';
  $this->{$property} = array(preg_quote($openTag), preg_quote($closeTag));
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can define your Blade content tags in your `routes.php` file:

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');
```

EDIT: You can add `@` in front of the brackets, so Blade won't render it.

```
@{ var }
```

or you can pass the directive for blade not to render part of the HTML using `@verbatim` keyword.

```
@verbatim
<div>
    {{ var }}
</div>
@endverbatim
```

Comment: Problem is using blade with angular, it's why I want to change one of two sintax... 
"nhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ':' at column 6 in [{{ Auth::User()->email }}] in UserComponent@27:101 ("                                       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" [ERROR ->]value="{{ Auth::User()->email }}">"
Because, is been confusing in angular and blade brackets